# Handling exceptions before startup

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, startup, custom-error-pages

I have an application that can throw an `InvalidOperationException` during the startup process ***before*** the host has been created. What I would like to do is capture this error, and handle it by displaying a static, custom error page (*i.e.* `ErrorPage.html`)

Is this possible? Everywhere I seem to look makes it seem as though this is an impossible task and that the default `500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start` is the only page that will appear in a situation where the host fails to establish by the time the exception is thrown.

Comment: If there is no host, who/what do you expect to serve/display the error? There is a reason for the HTTP 500 error code, and what you describe falls well with its definition.

Comment: How do you host your app? IIS?

Comment: @FireAlkazar yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve a custom error page on host errors generating 500 responses would be to use some gateway or proxy in front of your app. The idea would be to handle certain responses by showing some error content from the gateway.

Options would include [custom error pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error) in Azure Application Gateway or a middleware handler if using a [YARP](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/) proxy instance.

Comment: I didn't even think about this, a definite possibility. I will keep looking for a bit to see if there are any other options otherwise I may have to use this

Answer (score 1):

For IIS use `web.config` and add a section inside element `<system.webServer>`

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="30" path="ErrorPage.html" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

[Check docs for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/)

Comment: This would work but I would like to capture the specific exception `InvalidOperationException` to display an ErrorPage.html that is specific to that error, and there are other issues that could potentially raise the 500.30 error mentioned above. Like I mentioned, I don't know if this is possible to do but thank you for the documentation regardless.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the solution above and then, rather than using an `ErrorPage.html` file, you specify an ASP.NET Core endpoint (like a controller action if this is MVC). Inside the action you check the exception type (like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#access-the-exception) and return a view based on what exception type it is.

Comment: @ThomasArdal Unfortunately, to my understanding, the Controllers (and all of their actions) aren't even known about until the startup process is complete. So I don't think that this is a possibility either :/